# Generation of 3 state signal using 2 IOs of FPGA or MCU

Tags: signal

I need to generate a 3 state signal i.e 12 V , -12 V and 0 V square wave using 2 IOs from FPGA. I have a circuit shown below, 2 signals are generated i.e, 0 V to +12 V and -12 V to 0 V, but i need to combine these 2 signals into a single waveform so that 0 V, 12 V, 12 V states are not disturbed . when i combined these 2 outputs with a single wire, the output amplitude was -5 to +5 V but the expected is -12 V to +12 V .
I have given input of 0 to 3V3 signal from function generator and the input of 2nd opamp was exactly 180 deg out of phase (for generating this i used a inverter using transistor).
please suggest any solution for combining outputs.
[image]

IO1 : 1, IO2 : 0 --> output +12V
IO1 :0 , IO2: 1--> output -12V
IO1 : 0, IO2: 0 --> Output 0V
By uisng the above combination we can generate the 3 state signal using above circuit.
IO1 - input to non-inverting comparator
IO2 - input to inverting comparator

Frequency of the sqaure wave 32KHz

Comment: What's the load to be driven?

Comment: What is the purpose of T2 and T4? They seem to be connected as diodes.

Comment: Also, T1 and T3 are just emitter followers, so why not connect R9 and R10 directly to the opamps?

Comment: I need to connect this output to a 1: 1 ferrite core transformer

Comment: The usual meaning of 3-state is 0,1 and Z (high impedance). This would be better called ternary logic, or bipolar logic (as in the old HDB3 system)

Comment: Rather than using bipolar supplies, would a H bridge suffice? Something like a L293?